# Entire Track Velocity in Sony Vegas

Tags: vegas-pro

I have created a video+audio clip in Sony Vegas. After the work was completed, I decided to increase velocity a little bit (final percentage ~95% original).

In the project, I have several audio and video tracks, each of which obviously has multiple events.
I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse Drag</kbd> each individual **event**, but it seems even impossible to do the same when several events selected (only one event changes).

For both audio and viodeo, I need only velocity changed (**time stretch**, but no audio pitch shift), and all event points (transitions etc) change accordingly.

For audio, it seems possible to go to *Master FX* and add *Time Stretch* FX, but it only affects audio.

**How can I change velocity for each individual track (or, well, an entire project) with minimum hassle?**

P.S. Sony Vegas Pro 12.0, Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to increase the playback rate for the entire project is to use nested projects: Start new project and add your original project to the timeline as an event. Then Ctrl + Mouse Drag.

Comment: That's a very clever trick, thanks. Can I find it somewhere in the docs? I worry about the quality of video/audio rendering, e.g. would it lose any quality if the first project has source video samples assigned -5% velocity and then the wrapper project has +5% velocity.